# DD wrt bandwidth usage by user

Tags: router, bandwidth-control

Is there anyway on the dd-wrt to check to see how much bandwidth each client is using? I ask because I am in charge of looking over a group of routers connecting to a dd-wrt router and if a user is using too much at certain times I would like to be able to see that, and i am not all that familiar with dd-wrt.

Comment: [YAMon2](http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=259806&postdays=0&postorder=asc&start=0) is the only working monitor I could find. On that page is a PDF and a link to a [.doc tutorial](https://www.mediafire.com/?b488czq0xg242cg). There is [abandoned option](https://csdprojects.co.uk/ddwrt/), however the DISQUS thread seems that people are having reliability issues.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you want a bit of long term visibility to diagnose who is using a lot of bandwidth over time, DD-WRT has this cool feature called rFlow which can send data to a remote server that collects it. The server choice is up to you, but I'm personnally a big fan of nTop.

[This blog post](http://www.gofixit.com/?p=135) raves about the amount of visibility this can give you. Let me know if this is not what you were asking for.

Answer (score 1):

smoothwall seems to have the ability to do this as long as it's passing over one of it's interfaces. dd-wrt seems to be able to do a general overview but not by user. A cisco 2950 may be able to tell you per port utilization.

Answer (score 0):

Install a shibby version of Tomato (I said Tomato because generally Tomato is compatible with DD WRT devices); it allows you to monitor IP traffic based on IP addresses and hostnames.

http://tomato.groov.pl/